# Tamanho da fonte no jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports

Alguém saberia me explicar, porque não altera o tamanho da fonte ao gerar o pdf?

A fonte que está definida, é o padrão SansSerif **TAMANHO 15**, porém sempre aparece no pdf o **tamanho 10** Porque?

**Ps..: lembrando que a opção PdfEmbedded esta marcada!**

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que faltar .jar da fonte em questão no seu projeto, procura um .jar do seu gosto e adiciona na biblioteca do seu projeto!